# Set height of main container equal to its content

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper that has a dropdown element. The wrapper has a height of `fit-content`. Currently the wrappers height is equal to the `input` elements height found in the drop down but it ignores the height of the `ul` in the drop down. How can I make the height of the wrapper equal to the height of the `input` plus the height of the `ul`? Thanks in advance.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 95%;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: saddlebrown;
}

.wrapper .dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.wrapper .dropdown input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.wrapper .dropdown ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .dropdown ul li a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Locate your item" />
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `position: static` in `ul`. like  `.wrapper .dropdown ul{ position: static }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this problem because according to the bootstrap class "dropdown-menu" CSS is set to be `position: absolute;` but in your case you need it to be `position: relative;` so that your wrapper class can consider this `<ul>` as its child element.

So you need to add some CSS to make your `<ul>` as `position: relative;`.

Current CSS for `<ul>` is:

```
.wrapper .dropdown ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

change it to

```
.wrapper .dropdown ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper .dropdown ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative
}
```